# How can I use SDI-12 to communicate with a sensor?

Tags: serial

I have sensors connected to the serial port GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi, and these sensors require communication in the [SDI-12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDI-12) format. The only problem is, I can't find any online resources indicating how to use this communication protocol on a Raspberry Pi.

Can someone point me in the direction of a tutorial or some other information this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a SDI-12 USB dongle?

Comment: Presumably you've read this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=5675 It sounds to me like you need a separate bus as an intermediary, you won't be able to just connect the sensors to the pi.